# Can the representations be irreducible, inequivalent and equal?

Tags: representation-theory

I'm reading Steinberg's *Representation theory of finite groups.* In the second and third exercise here:

> [image]

I am a bit confused: What are those two cases? It references proposition $4.2.3$, which is:

> [image]

Is condition $1$ of $4.2.8$, condition $a$ of the $4.2.3$ and $2$ of the $4.2.8$, condition $b$ of $4.2.3$? If so, I'm a bit confused: Can the representations be irreducible, inequivalent and equal?

Comment: Part 2 of 4.2.8 is an inner product of $\varphi$ with itself, it has nothing to do with $\rho$.

Comment: @Joppy I am confused then. What is the difference of the two cases then?

Comment: Where is the exercise?